# Depth First Search Adjacency

Tags: python, dictionary, search, graph

Program that checks if a *directed graph* is strongly connected

I have a defaultdict:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'SanFrancisco': {'Houston': '1000'},
 'LA': {'Ames': '300', 'SanFrancisco': True, 'Detroit': '200'}, 
'NYC': {'LA': '3000'}, 'Austin': {'Houston': '500'}}) 
# myDefaultDict = collections.defaultdict(dict)
```

And a set containing all the distinct Strings:

```
{'Austin', 'LA', 'NYC', 'Ames', 'Detroit', 'Houston', 'SanFrancisco'}
# myNewSet
```

Now here is my code:

```
for i in myNewSet:
    break
    graph_DFT(i)

def graph_DFT(start):
    functionSet = set()
    myStack = []
    myStack.append(start)
    if not myStack:
        node = myStack.pop()
        # for neighbor in node's adjacent node
            #  if neighbor not visited - i.e. not in functionSet
                  # functionSet.add(neighbor)
                  # myStack.append(neighbor)
```

Note: My defaultdict can contain directed strings with optional edge weights.

So how can I check for an adjacent node? To be honest I'm not *100%* sure what an adjacent node is in my example. The nesting confuses me. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Start by explaining what you *think* an adjacent node is. We'll go from there.

Comment: @aryamccarthy Is it any node that the original one points to?

Comment: Good. Let's continue this in chat. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144105/room-for-aryamccarthy-and-coder117

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without giving away too much, I'll explain this.

You can iterate through the keys of a dict like this:

```
for k in mydict:
    ...
```

In your example:

```
for neighbor in G[node]: # Assumes your defaultdict is `G`.
    ...
```

Since the keys are the adjacent nodes, this is how you can operate on them.